# Cannot access my Virtual Machine after install sftp server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a small virtual machine (f1-micro) on google cloud platform. It has been running daily without issues for more than a year. Some days ago I tried to install an sftp server. I installed some packages and create some users. Since then I'm not able to accces it :(.

Somebody knows what can I do to recover the access? Maybe, there is the option to move the data on the hard disk to another "fresh" virtual machine?

Thanks,
Ferran

Comment: Google Cloud VMs already have an SFTP server installed as part of OpenSSH. What did you configure? Edit your question with details, otherwise, we can only guess. Read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, make sure you are posting on the correct Stack Exchange site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ie post on either ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, to be honest, I don't remember exactly what I did. I installed some packages and created some users. But my issue now is that I cannot enter to my VM. I'm asking if there is a way to enter or, at least, to read the hard disk.